# React-Rest app, where to fetch data from database

Tags: django, reactjs, rest

I have an App composed by back-end: Python with Django and Django REST, and front-end composed of React.

Right now I have Excel files with data, which I import with python in json format to the back-end, so they are available for a fetch in the front-end via REST-url like [here](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/tutorial-api-django-rest-react/#Django_REST_with_React_building_a_React_form).

I am now translating my data into a web-based-database to be queried into my app.
But I have questions regarding the structure of my app with this change.

I have url-based queries for my new database.
Should I continue to import the queries in the back-end REST framework and, from there, to React?
Or should I use the url-based queries directly inside my React, substituting the REST url calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found some sources that presented me two ways of solving the problem

Case 1:
Have the JSON Query importation on server side in your back-end and pass this data to your API (REST in my case).

Basic source: https://www.valentinog.com/blog/tutorial-api-django-rest-react/

Pros:

1. Do not need to change the structure for the rest of my application. The data layer continues the same, as before I was working with an Excel file and now I just change to a JSON Query.
2. The connection between server-client continues to be straight forward
3. Credential systems can be applied more easily for the data will be stored in your API

Cons

1. Harder to implement
2. Connection between python and url queries must have individual settings (url-queries are usually browser-based, and some queries can't be performed in python)
3. Harder to debug

Case 2: Query data with a native fetch Javascript method and handle the data in client side.

Basic Sources:https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-fetching-data/

https://blog.hellojs.org/fetching-api-data-with-react-js-460fe8bbf8f2

Pros:

1. Faster and easier to implement
2. Easier to debug
3. Javascript handles queries in a simpler way than python

Cons:

1. Credential system can't be applied
2. Less secure/robust method
3. Double connection between client and server (client-queries and client-API), because the API would still be maintained to store local information.

Answer (score 0):

You can get an idea by referring this url. 
https://www.andreasreiterer.at/connect-react-app-rest-api/

this describing about how to bind data using REST APIs in react.